# After upgrading to 19.04, what should i do with all PPA's that has been disabled for some reason?

Tags: ppa, 19.04

Since for software/OS update, PPA can play a vital role. So:

- Should I enable them all? Or should I enable those which say "Disco"?
- Or should I remove all which doesn't say "Disco"?

App update is important. Running "**apt-get update**" doesn't check for update unless I resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot of "Software & Update" center]

*Just in case, this might be useful for this case:*

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
alexlarsson-ubuntu-flatpak-cosmic.list
alexlarsson-ubuntu-flatpak-cosmic.list.save
apandada1-ubuntu-brightness-controller-cosmic.list
apandada1-ubuntu-brightness-controller-cosmic.list.save
bit-team-ubuntu-stable-cosmic.list
bit-team-ubuntu-stable-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
bit-team-ubuntu-stable-cosmic.list.save
communitheme-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list
communitheme-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.save
gnome-shell-extensions-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list
gnome-shell-extensions-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
gnome-shell-extensions-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
google-chrome.list.save
libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list
libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.save
mysql.list
mysql.list.distUpgrade
mysql.list.save
ne0sight-ubuntu-chrome-gnome-shell-cosmic.list
ne0sight-ubuntu-chrome-gnome-shell-cosmic.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-apps-cosmic.list
noobslab-ubuntu-apps-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
noobslab-ubuntu-apps-cosmic.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-icons-cosmic.list
noobslab-ubuntu-icons-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
noobslab-ubuntu-icons-cosmic.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-themes-cosmic.list
noobslab-ubuntu-themes-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
noobslab-ubuntu-themes-cosmic.list.save
oguzhaninan-ubuntu-stacer-cosmic.list
oguzhaninan-ubuntu-stacer-cosmic.list.save
rvm-ubuntu-smplayer-cosmic.list
rvm-ubuntu-smplayer-cosmic.list.save
scribus-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list
scribus-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
scribus-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.save
shutter-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list
shutter-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.save
sublime-text.list
sublime-text.list.distUpgrade
sublime-text.list.save
ubuntu-mozilla-security-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list
ubuntu-mozilla-security-ubuntu-ppa-cosmic.list.save
umang-ubuntu-indicator-stickynotes-cosmic.list
umang-ubuntu-indicator-stickynotes-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
umang-ubuntu-indicator-stickynotes-cosmic.list.save
vscode.list
vscode.list.distUpgrade
vscode.list.save
webupd8team-ubuntu-java-cosmic.list
webupd8team-ubuntu-java-cosmic.list.distUpgrade
webupd8team-ubuntu-java-cosmic.list.save
windscribe-repo.list
windscribe-repo.list.distUpgrade
windscribe-repo.list.save
```

Comment: Enabling/disabling PPA depends solely on your needs. Also, it is not necessary that all PPA are ready for Disco as of now. Do confirm before modifying any PPA so that you don't get errors. Enabling PPA whoch don't say disco might create problems or even break the system.

Comment: so according to u, I can safely enable those PPA which say "Disco" or not? @Kulfy

Comment: Yes you can enable PPA which says disco but I'm not sure if you really need Source Code of packages. Also, contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder don't matter, but the content of those files matter. Moreover, since you have webupd8team's repository as well, it's better to keep it disable since it has been discontinued on April 16, 2019.

Comment: Since it has been discontinued, what's the point of keeping them?! I am talking about "webupd8team". Is it ok to remove PPA which say "Cosmic" since it denotes 18.10? @Kulfy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal Package Archives (PPA) are used to install packages which are not in [official repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#The_Four_Main_Repositories) of Ubuntu or they contain an old version of the package. So, using a PPA solely depends on the needs of a user, like which packages he need.

Since Disco released a while ago, so all PPAs are not ready. You need to verify by going to PPA's page and check if they have ported packages for Disco as well (looks like  a tedious task). If you use other distributions' PPA, it might create inconsistency, dependency problems or even break your system.

In the screenshot you attached in the question, most PPAs are for Source Code. If want Source Code, you can enable them. I'll say ***it is safe to enable repositories you need that mentions "Disco"***.

PPA basically contains three parts: URI, distribution and component. In most of the cases URI and components remain same but distribution changes. If you want to modify all 3rd party PPAs in one go for Disco, run:

```
sudo sed 's/cosmic/disco/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

After that you can enable all repositories (if you need them). If you get some errors like "Release file not found", it means PPA isn't ready for Disco yet. So, it's better to let it be disabled.

**Additional Info**: It seems you are using webupd8team's PPA for Oracle's JDK. But this PPA has been discontinued as of April 16, 2019 ([reference](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)). So it's better to delete it.